# readxl Iterate over multiple worksheets in a workbook while passing additional arguments

Tags: r, readxl

Readxl provides a good solution to iterate over multiple sheets and name those sheets, which works great.

https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/readxl-workflows.html

```
path <- readxl_example("datasets.xlsx")
path %>% 
 excel_sheets() %>% 
 set_names() %>% 
 map(read_excel, path = path)
```

However I need to pass additional arguments to read_excel..such as below being the desired output.

```
read_excel("datasets.xlsx",col_names = FALSE, skip = 1)
```

Solutions I tried

```
path <- readxl_example("datasets.xlsx")
path %>% 
 excel_sheets() %>% 
 set_names() %>% 
 map(read_excel(col_names = FALSE, skip = 1), path = path)
```

and

```
read_excel_func <- function(y){
 readxl::read_excel(y, col_names = FALSE, skip = 1)
}

path <- readxl_example("datasets.xlsx")
path %>% 
 excel_sheets() %>% 
 set_names() %>% 
 map(read_excel_func, path = path)
```

Comment: This isn't actually a `readxl` issue, but an issue of how to pass arguments in `map` functions. You can use formula notation around the function. In the last block, you're passing `path = path` to a function that doesn't take an argument named `path`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this using the anonymous function call with `~`

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
path %>% 
 excel_sheets() %>% 
   set_names() %>% 
   map(~ read_excel(.x, col_names = FALSE, skip = 1, path = path))
```

---

Or simply pass the arguments in `map` as `path`

```
path %>% 
  excel_sheets() %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map(read_excel, col_names = FALSE, skip = 1, path = path)
```

Comment: perfect solution!